# jenkins running in k8s pod container, throw java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/cicd_tool/ci_conf@tmp

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins

When using the k8s plug-in in the jenkins pipeline, no matter the official docker image pulled or the docker image I made myself, when using the jenkins dir command to switch to a multi-level directory, a java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException exception will be reported. If it is only a single-level directory, for example: dir("cicd_tool"), there will be no error. Why does this happen?

```
podTemplate(containers: [containerTemplate(name: 'cicd-orin', image: getImage('cicd-orin'), ttyEnabled: true,resourceRequestCpu: '6000m',resourceRequestMemory: '6000Mi',alwaysPullImage:true, command: 'cat')]){
    node(POD_LABEL){
        container('cicd-orin') {
            try{
                stage('clean workspace'){
                    sh "ls -A |xargs rm -rf"
                }

                stage("update code"){
                    updateCode("https://code.hozonauto.com:10443/CICD/cicd_tool.git", "master")
                }

                dir("cicd_tool/ci_orin/ci_conf"){
                    sh "pwd"
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                println ex
            }
        }
    }
}
```